# Window.print() function and document.execCommand('print') fucntion is not working in MS Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I am trying to print html report in my application using window.print() function, works well in all browsers but nothing happens in Microsoft Edge.

Any alternate function to print in Microsoft Edge ?

I tried the function - document.execCommand('print').
Tested this in chrome, works well there but doesn't work in MS Edge.

Comment: strange. could check the error console for some error message and post it in here?

Comment: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/17148061/

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no error message in the console of Microsoft Edge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your Microsoft Edge browser version, both the window.print() method and the document.execCommand("print") script works well on my side (using Microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0), the result like this:
[image]

sample code:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Print this page</button>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        //window.print();
        document.execCommand("print");
    }
</script>
```

So, you could try to upgrade the Microsoft Edge browser version to version 44.18362.1.0 or the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

works fine if you put your windows.print command on the bottom of the page (obviously edge must fully load the page first and then execute print command)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29968237)